# disappearance of a component after reloading the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Everything works fine. Content changes after pressing NavLink, but when I reload the page, the content disappears. Аlthough, interestingly, the URL remains the same. How to fix, or so it should be?

*Before reloading *
[image]

*After reloading *
[image]

Code:

App.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Nav from './components/Nav/Nav';
import Profile from './components/Profile/Profile.jsx';
import Dialog from './components/Dialog/Dialog'
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Nav />
        <Route path='/profile' component={Profile} />
        <Route path='/dialog' component={Dialog} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Dialog.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import style from './Dialog.module.css'
import MessageOleg from '../Messages/MessageOleg'
import MessageMax from '../Messages/MessageMax'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'


const Dialog = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div className={style.dialog}>
                <div className={style.users}>
                    <div className={style.user}> <NavLink to='/messageOleg'> Oleg </NavLink>  </div><br />
                    <div className={style.user}> <NavLink to='/messageMax' >Max </NavLink>   </div><br />
                    <div className={style.user}> Nata  </div><br />
                    <div className={style.user}> Fuflo   </div><br />
                    <div className={style.user}> Kiko   </div><br />
                </div>
                <hr />
                <Route path='/messageOleg' component={MessageOleg} />
                <Route path='/messageMax' component={MessageMax} />
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default Dialog;
```

MessageOleg.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import style from './MessageOleg.module.css'

const MessageOleg = () => {
    return (
        <div className={style.messages}>
        <div className={style.message}>
            Hey
        </div>
    </div>
    )

}

export default MessageOleg;
```

Comment: Where is the `<Switch/>` component?

Comment: @Chris Using <Switch> is completely optional

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to nest routers like that. How to do this properly is explained here: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting (I'm pretty sure that it only works fine by accident, which is why it breaks immediately when you refresh) Anyway, the basic idea is to use a URL like `/dialog/messageOleg` to display the messages, and use nested `<Route>`s inside a single `BrowserRouter` to achieve that.

Comment: I changed link from '/messageOleg' to '/dialog/messageOleg' and it works. Thanks anyway